# How does this +/-15 V power supply from the LT3467 datasheet work?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, boost

I came across a problem where I need to generate a +/-15 V power supply. I searched and found this reference design in the [LT3467 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3467afe.pdf):

[image]

How does it work?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simulation of the positive voltage booster:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdEGcx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The equivalent circuit of the +15 V output.*

[image]

*Figure 2. V<sub>A</sub>, V<sub>B</sub> and V<sub>C</sub> when V1 is a 0 - 15 V squarewave.*

- C1 decouples the output from the switched DC from L1.
- D1 charges up C2.
- D2 clamps the right hand side of C1 at 0 V when V1 goes negative.
- In the LT schematic R1 and R2 provide a feedback voltage proportional to the output voltage. They're in the ratio 147:13.3 and since the output voltage is 15 V I would guess that the chip regulates so that it gets \$ \frac {13.3}{147} \times 15 = 1.33 \ \text V \$ back on its FB input. (I didn't check the datasheet.)

The -15 V rail works in the same way but without feedback. This simplifies the design and since C5 = C4 and C3 = C2 the negative voltage should mirror the positive voltage well enough for typical applications.

Answer (score 2):

The upper part is almost a classic step-up converter, except they add AC coupling capacitor (C4). So you can look it up on the internet.

The lower part of a circuit (negative part) is also a classic circuit "capacitive inverter/ voltage doubler". I do not know the exact name for  this circuit.

When the SW pin (internal MOSFET N-chanel connected between SW and GND) is open the voltage at this pin is high (15V + 0.3V or more).

The C5 will be charged to arond 15V.

[image]

And when the SW pin is LOW (0V)now the previous charged C5 capacitor will start discharge phase and charge the output capacitor (C3).

[image]

And after a couple of cycle charging/discharging the negative voltage  will reach -15V.

Also I found this simulation of lower part of a circuit:

https://www.multisim.com/content/d2e88qRjgcLEh6SRT3PAa3/switched-diode-capacitor-positive-dc-to-negative-dc-voltage-inverter/open/